# BeautifulSoup ... AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hope that someone can help...

Print (lst_rooms.text) work correctly.

Print (lst_bed.text, lst_bath.text) resulted... 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Thank you.

.

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')

for lst_rooms in soup.find_all('li', class_='lst-rooms'):

    lst_bed = lst_rooms.find('span', class_='lst-bed')
    lst_bath = lst_rooms.find('span', class_='lst-bath')

    print(lst_rooms.text)
    print(lst_bath.text)
    print(lst_bed.text)



result
-------
<li class="lst-rooms"><span class="bed" title="3 Beds">3 <i class="pg-icon pgicon-bedroom"></i></span> <span class="bath" title="2 Baths">2 <i class="pg-icon pgicon-shower"></i></span></li>

<li class="lst-rooms"><span class="bed" title="2 Beds">2 <i class="pg-icon pgicon-bedroom"></i></span> <span class="bath" title="2 Baths">2 <i class="pg-icon pgicon-shower"></i></span></li>
```

Comment: NoneType just means that the item isnt found.   Which makes sense from your resuit because you are looking for a class:  *lst-bed* but the class is just *bed*

Comment: @Fallenreaper        Thanks for pointing out the mistakes ...

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that it is returning None because it didnt find anything matching your params.  That being said, i did noticed that you are looking for spans with class: *lst-bed* but in the sample code you gave, the list options show a span with class *bed*.

I presume that if you change the class parameter accordingly, you will find the results you seek.

Comment: No problem.  If it solves your problem, you can check in in order to show the next person.